# Submanifold given by an immersion open onto its image

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I was wondering if the following is true:

> Let $M,N$ be two manifolds such that $\dim M\leq \dim N$ and $f:M\rightarrow N$ an smooth immersion.
>
> Assume that for any open set $U\subset M$, $f(U)$ is open in $f(M)$, does it imply that $f(M)$ is a submanifold of $N$ ?

I know that if we also ask $f$ to be injective, then it is an embedding and $f(M)$ is automatically a submanifold of $N$. But without this assumption, I am not sure that the result holds.

Being an open map on its image somehow tells us that there is no bad self-intersection in $f(M)$ but I am not sure this is enough to have a submanifold.

Comment: Is $\dim M \le \dim N$ redundant please? I think it's implied by immersion.

Comment: Actually, I notice $f: M \to N$ is actually not given as open. If it were, I think we could argue (that [$f$ is a local diffeo or at least](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301330/are-open-immersions-equivalent-to-local-diffeomorphisms-not-algebraic-geometry)) that $f(M)$ is open. What's given is that $\tilde f: M \to f(M)$ is open, i.e. $f$ is open onto its image. Therefore, I think the title should be changed.

Comment: Is the [converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302347/an-injective-immersion-is-an-embedding-if-and-only-if-open-onto-image-if-and-onl) true?

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is a local imbedding and since $\tilde f: M \to f(M)$ is an open map, there exists a coordinate patch $V \subset N$ around every point of $f(M)$ such that $V \cap N = \mathbb{R}^m$.  $f(M)$ is therefore a submanifold of $N$.

More precisely:

Fix $p \in M$. Since $f$ is a local imbedding, there exist open sets $U \subset M$, $V \subset N$, $p \in U$ and charts $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, \psi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\psi \circ f  \circ \phi^{-1}$ is the inclusion $\mathbb{R}^m \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Now since $f(U)$ is open in $F(M)$ we may shrink $V$ (if necessary) so that $V \cap f(M) = f(U) = \psi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^m)$.  The existence of such a chart, $(V, \psi)$, at every point $f(p)$ of $f(M)$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $f(M)$ to be an imbedded submanifold of $N$.

Comment: Is $\dim M \le \dim N$ redundant please? I think it's implied by immersion.

Comment: Is the [converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302347/an-injective-immersion-is-an-embedding-if-and-only-if-open-onto-image-if-and-onl) true?

Comment: @SeleneAuckland are you asking whether a topological imbedding is an open map to its image?

Comment: btw talking about a subset of a manifold being a sub manifold can get very confusing.  imo it's better to talk about maps (either injective immersions or imbeddings) as submanifolds.

Comment: then if you still want to talk about subsets, you could say "image of an injective immersion" or "image of an imbedding"

Comment: Thanks. I'm asking if "for an injective immersion $F: N \to M$ with $F(N)$ as a regular/embedded submanifold, and not just an immersed submanifold, of $M$, we have that $F$ is open onto its image" ($F$ *open onto its image* is defined as $\tilde F: N \to F(N)$ is open) is true.

Comment: @SeleneAuckland it seems to me the answer is yes: N --> F(N) is a smooth bijection with non degenerate derivative between two manifolds. so it's a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks Tim kinsella! You [can answer on the other question if you want](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302347/an-injective-immersion-is-an-embedding-if-and-only-if-open-onto-image-if-and-onl).

Comment: "Since $f$ is a local imedding and an open map" Actually $\tilde f: M \to f(M)$ is the open map, not necessarily $f: M \to N$? I think you mean "Since $f$ is a local imbedding and an open map onto its mage"

Comment: @SeleneAuckland yes you're right