# An injective immersion is an embedding if and only if open onto image if and only if image is (regular) submanifold?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, differential-geometry, differential-topology, submanifold

Update: Tim kinsella appears to say yes [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568160/submanifold-given-by-an-open-immersion#comment6798367_570201).

---

Related:

1. [An injective smooth function with injective differential must have a continuous inverse?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125017/an-injective-smooth-function-with-injective-differential-must-have-a-continuous)
2. I think my question is equivalent to the converse of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568160/submanifold-given-by-an-open-immersion).

Let $N$ and $M$ be smooth manifolds [with dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if). Let $p \in N$. Let $F: N \to M$ be a smooth map.

A. $F$ is said to be an *embedding* if $F$ is an immersion and a topological embedding. (You may have a [different but equivalent definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297560/equivalent-definitions-for-smooth-embedding).)

B. Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. A map, not necessarily injective or continuous, $F: X \to Y$ is said to be a *topological embedding* if $\tilde F: X \to F(X)$ is a homemorphism.

C. $F$ is said to be *open onto its image* if $\tilde F$ is open.

D. If $F$ is an injective immersion, then $\tilde F$ is already injective ($\tilde F$ is injective if and only if $F$ is too), surjective and continuous (because $F$ is continuous because $F$ is smooth). Therefore, $F$ is an embedding if and only if $F$ is open onto its image.

**Question**: Is $\tilde F$ open if and only if $F$ is an embedding if and only if $F(N)$ is a regular submanifold ([with dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if)) of $M$? I think yes. Please verify.

Suppose $\tilde F$ open. Show $F(N)$ is a regular submanifold of $M$: Done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568160/submanifold-given-by-an-open-immersion) (which assumes [open onto image rather than open](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1229975)).

Suppose $F(N)$ is a regular submanifold of $M$. Show $\tilde F$ is open.

1. Because $F(N)$ is a regular submanifold of $M$, $F(N)$ is a manifold, so $\tilde F$ is a map of manifolds, so we can talk about $\tilde F$ as smooth or not smooth. Unsurprisingly, because $F(N)$ is a regular submanifold of $M$, $\tilde F$ is smooth by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wn3q.png). Thus, we can talk about $\tilde F$ possibly being an immersion, submersion, local diffeomorphism, embedding, diffeomorphism, etc.
2. $\tilde F$ is an immersion if and only if $F$ is an immersion, by (1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299401/tilde-f-immersion-is-equivalent-to-f-immersion),
3. $\tilde F$ is a surjective immersion, by (2) and (D),
4. $\dim F(N) = \dim N$, by (3) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714579/bijective-immersion-is-a-diffeomorphism) (or by (3) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302411/dimension-of-domain-is-greater-than-less-than-equal-to-dimension-of-range-for-a), I guess; Maybe the two arguments, one of using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714579/bijective-immersion-is-a-diffeomorphism) and one of using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302411/dimension-of-domain-is-greater-than-less-than-equal-to-dimension-of-range-for-a) are actually equivalent).
5. $\tilde F$ is both a (surjective) submersion and a (surjective) local diffeomorphism, by (4) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298447/for-manifolds-of-the-same-dimension-are-submersions-equivalent-to-immersions).
6. Both submersions and local diffeomorphisms are open maps.
7. By (5) and (6), $\tilde F$ is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tilde{F}: N \rightarrow F(N)$ is a smooth bijection with non degenerate derivative between two manifolds. so it's a diffeomorphism. in particular, it's an open map.

Comment: The fact that a bijective immersion must be a diffeomorphism is non-trivial. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/714658/394668) is proven with detail.